# CMOS Timing specifications

Tags: cmos

[image]

In the image above, why does current flow backwards toward the left GND but not toward the right ?

Comment: Because the drain is a lower impedance port (with Vin HIGH)  than the gate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow shows the current flowing through the channel of the nMOS element of the left gate, as that transistor turns on due to a rising Vin voltage, as the Cw distributed capacitance discharges.

On the right, Cw is connected to the gate of the MOSFETs, which are insulated from the channels. There is no path for current to flow to ground through the right, aside from a very small transient associated with the gate capacitance of those MOSFETs. A more comprehensive model could show a small current charging those gate capacitances, but the majority of the stored charge in Cw is moved via the channels of the MOSFETs on the left.

Answer (score 1):

CMOS is not as shown with current sink rather complementary switches much lower than load by at least 5 decades of resistance... e.g. 50 Ohm  to >5M

think of CMOS driver as 25-300 ohm SPDT switching depending on Vdd max rating and actual. Newer 3.6V logic used at 3.3V is 25 Ohms +/-50% over temp.

So the only current in between is the Ciss input capacitance and limited by series R.

High side drives current to right while low side switch sinks current to left.

Series R makes it more linear, yet Ciss changes during commutation so it is non linear.  So a fixed input cap ≈ >10pf makes it linear.

it is always Pch high and Nch low with Vt about 1/3 to 1/2 of Vdd Max for the threshold ≈100uA current so both switches are active at Vdd/2 but lower current to be safe. This current is inside the driver not between parts and is designed to give smooth fast rise times rated with 30  pF std. load.

Cw you will notice is the trace capacitance and partially differentiates the signal if R was very small to get a faster signal, then it has inductance and thus a know impedance of trace at RF rise times due to root(L/C) ratio and then it gets a bit more complex with possible ringing on long traces since the load is mismatched, yet now here as series R dominates lower f cutoff if > RdsOn on driver, this does not occur.

So Rpu and Rpd are the RdsOn values in each CMOS switch driver for a SPDT switch.